# Unable to display JSON fromated database result using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have Codeigniter application which fetches data from database as result array, converts data to Json and displays the results. However I keep getting undefined as display result.

Model

```
 $this->db->where('product_name',$sid);
      //  $this->db->select('product_title');
        $res = $this->db->get('products');
         $data = $res->result_array();  
         return $data;
```

View:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#findsubmit').click(function() {
        $.get("/products/index.php/find/lookup",{id : $('#id').val() },function(data) {

            $('#result').html('Product name: ' + data.product_name);
            //+ ' Last name: ' + data.lastname);
        },"json");
        return false;
});
</script>
```

Resulting array I receive in Firebug:

```
[{"category":"camera","product_name":"Sony HX20"},{"category":"camera","product_name":"Canon SZ220"}]
```

If I create simple array like this all works fine:

```
return array('category' => 'camera','product_name' => 'Sony HX20');
```

Resulting array I receive in Firebug:

```
{"category":"camera","product_name":"Sony HX20"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON data, you receive an array of several results: `data.product_name` is not defined, but `data[0].product_name` and `data[1].production_name` are.

You should try to either return only one result (like the one you build manually), or iterate on `data`.

Edit: here's a sample on how to use `$.each`:

```
var names = 'Product name: ';
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    if (index > 0) {names += '; ';}
    names += element.product_name;
});
$('#result').html(names);
```

Comment: Thanks now it works. Any suggestion on how to iterate on data? Just use for loop?

Comment: You can use a loop or the jQuery function `$.each`

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to add it to my code as I am quite new to Jquery.